# Is this $2^{\lceil\log_2 d\rceil}$ inequality true?

Tags: diophantine-approximation

Is it true that $\frac{2^{t}-1}{t}+\frac d{t}>\frac d{\lceil\log_2 d\rceil}$ holds always for every large enough $d\in\mathbb N$ and $t\geq\lceil\log_2 d\rceil$?

Comment: Is this related to the original post with ">d+1" ?

Comment: I think I can prove this inequality holds unconditionally for all $d>0$ and all $t>0$ and the bound on $t\geq\lceil\log_2d\rceil$ does not matter.

Comment: @T.... Then you should give an answer to your own qusetion.

Comment: I meant if $t\in\mathbb Z$ also holds.